# How can I access an array in one of my classes?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a structure called myGV designed to hold a few global variables. While everything works, I cannot figure out how to access an array through all properties. This is what I'm trying:

```
myGV.guessBar = GuessBar : SKSpriteNode
```

The GuessBar has 6 children of type: `GuessSlot : SKSpriteNode`. `GuessBar` stores the instances in an array.

Here is the code for `GuessBar`:

```
class GuessBar : SKSpriteNode {
    var guessSlots : [GuessSlot] = []

    init(color: SKColor, size: CGSize) {
       super.init(texture: nil, color: color, size: size)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
 }
```

Here is the code where I fill the arrays in the guessBar

```
func createGuessBar(color: SKColor, size: CGSize, factor: Int) -> GuessBar
{
    let myGuessBar = GuessBar(color : color, size: size)

    //other unrelated code

    for x in 0...5 {
        let mGuessSlot = GuessSlot(color: .clear, size: CGSize(width: iFactor, height: rFactor), width: myGuessBar.size.width,  iFactor: x, guessBarRef: myGuessBar)
        myGuessBar.guessSlots.append(mGuessSlot)
    }
    //other unrelated code

    return myGuessBar
}
```

The way I see it, everything is running fine. If I expand the guessSlots in the `debugger` it lists each value. I just can't get the syntax right, going by the last line in the debugger, to access that array from my main structure `myGV`.

[image: Debugger info]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my fault. It's right there in the debugger too. My SKSpriteNode should be declared as the subclass, not an SKSpriteNode. That's why I can't access the array. The array exists in my subclass.